# how to count rows of select count using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

i want to get total rows number same like

select count(*) from (select count(*) from tableA group by column1)

i m searching for my problem on net, but not find solution

Comment: cant you just do `select count of distinct column1, column2`? why do you want to count and do a count on that?

Comment: actully i want same like
select COUNT(a.y0_) from (
select distinct COUNT(centermas1_.CenterID) as y0_ 
 from LinkMaster this_ inner join CenterMaster centermas1_ on this_.CenterId=centermas1_.CenterID 
 where 1=1 
)

Answer (score 1):

Use Projections:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```